# LibGDX scrollpane disable scrolling x

Tags: libgdx, scrollpane

I have a scrollpane in libgdx. Scrolling up and down is enabled(with touches), and i want to scroll it to left and right with a button, but disable scrolling with touches.

```
'rightButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
 public void changed (ChangeListener.ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
 scrollPane.layout();
 scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled(false, false);
 scrollPane.setScrollX(scrollPane.getMaxX());
 scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled(false, false);
 scrolled = true;
 }
 });
'
```

Here is my RightButton listener, but it doesnt scroll the X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollTo()` is overloaded method of `ScrollPane`, you can use this method and scroll your pane to specified offset. Call this method in your Listener's method.

I have tested, you can test my code.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Texture img;
    Stage stage;
    ScrollPane scrollPane;
    Group group;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        stage=new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        final float w=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        final float h=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        group=new Group();
        group.setSize(2*w,h);
        scrollPane=new ScrollPane(group);
        scrollPane.setSize(w,h);
        scrollPane.setFlickScroll(false);

        stage.addActor(scrollPane);

        Image image1=new Image(img);
        image1.setPosition(w*.5f, h/2f);
        image1.setScale(.5f);
        group.addActor(image1);

        Image image2=new Image(img);
        image2.setPosition(w*.75f, h/3f);
        image2.setScale(.5f);
        group.addActor(image2);

        stage.addListener(new ClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

                float offsetPositionX=w*.5f;
                float offsetPositionY=0;

                scrollPane.scrollTo(offsetPositionX,offsetPositionY,w,h);

                super.clicked(event, x, y);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        img.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my problem is still up. I want to disable scrolling the scrollpane scrolling in the X axis by touches and it should only be scrolled by buttons

Comment: check my updated answer. You can remove flickScrollListener from your scrollpane by  scrollPane.setFlickScroll(false); and after that it will not scroll by your touch.

Comment: Yeah, it souns good, but if i'm right it disables the scrolling by touch in the Y axis, is there a method which only diables the touch scrolling in X axis?